# Loading images from cache Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I use Glide with recyclerview .When I run my app on my device for first
 time (Using android studio) images loaded correctly but after press back and
 finish app then open app again images not load and I must click on cards(Click
 on card opens new activity) to load display images (it seems 
images cached but not load)
I enable all type of debug logging but don't get any
 exception or error

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(Uri.parse(image.getImage_url()))
     .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
           @Override
           public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                   return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource){
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                 return false;
             }
      })
      .into(holder.image);
```

This code in recyclerview adapter

Glide Version `3.7.0`

And this is layout of elements of adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_project_pro_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_view_image_holder"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

        <customfonts.MyTextViewLight
            android:id="@+id/activity_project_pro_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/design_name"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#aa000000"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/under_line"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:id="@+id/image_activity_share_btn"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:src="@drawable/card_share"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                        android:contextClickable="true"
                        android:layout_height="32dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:id="@+id/image_activity_save_btn"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:src="@drawable/card_downlaod"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:contextClickable="true"
                        android:layout_height="32dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>




</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Sorry for long post

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem few days back. I added diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) and dontAnimate() method in my glide call and it started working fine.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(Uri.parse(image.getImage_url()))
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
     .dontAnimate()
     .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
           @Override
           public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                   return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource){
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                 return false;
             }
      })
      .into(holder.image);
```

Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: I tested it before and test it again now but don't get result. @Shivam

Comment: I search a lot and find that the problem may be by calculate the size of image by Glide. be cause when i click on one of the cardviews(before loading images) all of images displayed suddenly @Shivam

Comment: It can be a case, my problem got resolved by adding these methods

Comment: do you know why when clicked load images?@Shivam

Comment: It depends on when are you getting image, if you already have image then for activity, you can load in onCreate and for fragment you can load in onCreateView

Comment: don't know my friend. seems problem is by `onSizeReady()` of image and Glide cache. no idea how to solve this problem.[issue on Glide repo github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1760)

Comment: Ok I will also check

Comment: .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
     .dontAnimate() worked out.Thanks @Shivam